# Server sees GET when I send POST in NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, ruby, heroku, sinatra, nsurlconnection

I have this code:

```
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    NSString *postString = [@"content=" stringByAppendingString:@"stuff here"];
    request.HTTPBody = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setValue:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:[postString length]] stringValue] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSError *requestError;
    NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;

    NSData *resp = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];
    NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[resp bytes] length:[resp length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

which I expect to send a post request with content=some stuff

But instead the server acts like is got a GET. What is wrong?

Here is my server side code (ruby, sinatra, heroku)

```
get '/messages' do
    @messages = Message.all
    erb :messages
end

get '/messages/:id' do
    Message.find(params[:id]).content
end

post '/messages' do
    @content = Message.new({:content => params[:content]})
    RestClient.post API_URL+"/messages", 
        :from => "idoor@idoor.heroku.com",
        :to => "drew.a.gross@gmail.com",
        :subject => "New Message from iDoor!",
        :html => @content.content
    @content.save
    @content.content
end
```

Here are the log files on the server. I don't understand what is going on exactly, it looks like there is a POST and a GET

```
2013-09-16T06:41:37.482489+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H16 desc="herokuapp redirect" method=POST path=/messages host=idoor.heroku.com fwd="129.97.131.0, 127.0.0.1" dyno= connect= service= status=301 bytes=
2013-09-16T06:41:37.741972+00:00 app[web.1]: 129.97.131.0 - - [16/Sep/2013 06:41:37] "GET /messages HTTP/1.1" 200 398 0.0850
2013-09-16T06:41:37.747154+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/messages host=idoor.herokuapp.com fwd="129.97.131.0" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=95ms status=200 bytes=398
```

Comment: Just read log file(s). If you see that there was logged a GET request - so the problem is on the client side.

Comment: The server sees some strange stuff, both a GET and a POST. I'll include the logs.

Comment: The log mentions a [`H16` code](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h16-redirect-to-herokuapp-com) which is redirecting the request. Perhaps the method is changing in part of that for some reason. Try updating your client code to use the `herokuapp.com` domain directly rather than `heroku.com`.

Comment: That worked. What a weird issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should encode your post body using the percent-encoding (not UTF-8).

Secondly, did you consider the possibility that it is your **server** who does something wrong.  Can you post the server-side code?

Comment: Done. It's written in ruby. The data I get in the response is a list of messages, not a single message.